# CPLEX Java - Quadratics not supported in this context by IloCplex

Tags: java, cplex

Is it possible to implement a multiple objective problem with quadratic constraints using CPLEX? I've tried to implement it using the staticLex method as follows:

```
cplex.add(cplex.minimize(cplex.staticLex(objArray)));
```

However it outputs the following exception:

```
Concert exception 'ilog.cplex.IloCplex$UnsupportedQException: CPLEX
Error: quadratics not supported in this context by IloCplex' caught
```

Is there any workaround?

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way, if this functionality is particularly important to you, you can file an RFE [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as stated in the release notes [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/CPLEX/ReleaseNotes/topics/releasenotes1290/newMultiObjOptimization.html), this is not supported with CPLEX 12.9 (emphasis mine):

> Optimization problems with multiple **linear** objective functions can be
>   specified in CPLEX.

If you move the quadratic part of the objective into a constraint via a dummy variable, it will result in a `CPLEX Error  1031: Not available for QCP.`